# In LMA is there a field or something that marks push upgrades or user upgrades?

Tags: trigger, email-template, appexchange, isv, lma

Is there a way I can query the LMA objects to find if a package version was upgraded via AppExchange or if it was a push upgrade? Which object/field?

The idea is to have a trigger so if it was a push upgrade send an email notification to the admin users and if it was a user upgrade via Appexchange to send a different email notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postinstall class to do that by checking the version and take action accordingly

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script_create.htm